# $regexMatch after converting number $toString not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This expression works:

```
db.users.findOne({ '$expr': { '$regexMatch': { input: { '$toString': '$contact_number' }, regex: /78316/ } }})
```

while expressions with regex's length greater than 5 chars does not return a result:

```
db.users.findOne({ '$expr': { '$regexMatch': { input: { '$toString': '$contact_number' }, regex: /783160/ } }})
```

Any help along the lines of matching pattern with numeric mongo field would be very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Add everything as text to the question please.

Comment: And include shell statement to populate the collection with one test document.

Comment: @D.SM apologies, I'm not very active here, trying to change that.

Comment: @Gibbs ans was very helpful :D, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you stored contact number as long.

And when you perform `toString`, it converted to scientific string notation. I am not sure whether it is converted by toString or mongo-drivers.

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/52h5BxOwoG6) - you can see how it converts when you convert to string

And when you look for 78316 it is part of string notation. Hence matches.

And when you search for 783160, it's not part of string notation. So returns no doc.

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzIsVms6z7M) - 78316e matches.

It happens because of default precision of scientific notation. And better store contact number as string if you can alter now.

Comment: Thanks Gibbs, this helps A LOT.
Was able to get it to work after using [$toLong](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aj9jDuq74IG) operator.

PS. changing contact_number to String now would not be a small refactor now, with unpredictable repercussions, both internally and for the apps using the apis we host.